# Figuring out the ISP of an Akamai CDN hosted site

Tags: ip, isp, cdn

I'm interested in the effective ISP hosting a website. The IP of the FQDN of the site leads to the [Akamai](http://akamai.com/) CDN.

> Q: May I somehow figure out, which effective ISP hosts the site?

This is of interest, since the site is an offering of a public service agency in Germany. In Germany, the GDPR is quite strict regarding what is and what is not OK regarding e.g. the country of an ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the website owner.

Seriously, if everything is configured correctly it should not be possible for you to deduce this from looking "behind the curtain" online - a CDN and a DoS protection service should not leak this information as it allows threat actors to bypass the security put in place by routing through the CDN.